# “Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages\User\EasyClangComplete.sublime-settings：18：1”

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to set up the EasyClangComplete, but I got the problem...

> Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in
>   Packages\User\EasyClangComplete.sublime-settings：18：1

Comment: Is this the only error you are seeing? In around half an hour a new version 6.0.0 is going to become available. There is a bunch of changes, so try if that fixes your issue.